# Strategy for up to 40 ADC inputs using alert feature

Tags: adc, multiplexer, phototransistor

I'm working on a project where I want to monitor 40 phototransistors (IR breaker beams), but without having to constantly poll the ADCs. Ideally I'd want a digital pin pulled when one of the beams is broken and then I'll poll the ADC(s) to find out exactly which one it was. I'll also need to be able to detect a change on each input regardless of the state of the others.

I see there are ADCs with programmable GPIOs and dedicated alert pin(s). I'm just a beginner, and I find - particularly with the programmable GPIO varieties - the datasheets confusing and I doubt I have the experience to successfully make use of those.

Then the variety with dedicated alert pins seem to be easier to program but don't seem to come any larger than 8-channel. Fewest parts please, particularly since the incredibly small IC packages will likely be hand-soldered. `AD7997` is currently the chip I'm considering, but would require 5 TSSOP footprints. I would probably AND the alert pins together to the host.

Are there any other ways to do this? Thanks for your input.

More project details: Beaglebone black, Node.js/bonescript, Phototransistor is the LTR-301.

**UPDATE 1**

Breaker beams will be broken or unbroken for large amounts of time.

Comment: What is the reason for using ADCs? Digital inputs would make more sense!

Comment: Is this a safety thing (eg. punch press guard) or security thing?

Comment: I like the digital idea.  Could you do something 'primitve' like the old DTL Nand gate.  Signal changes when on of the diode inputs is pulled low.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode%E2%80%93transistor_logic

Comment: @LeonHeller I was under the impression that photo transistors would not produce enough of an edge for digital input interrupts? I haven't tried it, though. Will try collector to digital input and see if it works.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Security

Comment: The AD7997's ALERT pin is open-drain and can be configured for active-low. This allows you to connect multiple ALERT pins together with a pull-up resistor to a single GPIO input pin. If any of the alerts asserts, it will pull the GPIO pin low. No diodes, gates, etc. needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 40 inputs that are normally at zero and you want to know if one of those signals has gone high you can use logic gates to detect this or if you want, you can use diode orring to give you one signal that tells your one of the inputs has risen high.

The same can be done if the inputs are normally high and one goes to 0V, It's fairly trivial with real voltage signals but a little more care has to be taken when the signals are from an open-collector as per a photo transistor - you've got to make sure the loading of the diodes/logic isn't too great to cause the signal problems.

By the way - using diodes means that the inputs remain independant and still individually readable should you choose to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure I could guarantee the inputs would be high or low, so any logic-level is probably out. Diode oring: after the first event I would be blind any any subsequent events. I should have specified that the beams are usually broken or unbroken for long periods of time.

Comment: OK but maybe make your question clearer - not mentioning logic level inconsistencies and that you need to be able to detect a change on any input no matter what the state of the other inputs are at is a big deal. If you could define logic levels a tad better then using exclusive or gates will do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, still learning. I understand the significance now, and have basic understanding of logic circuits. I think I'm hitting a wall with how that can apply to this, an IR phototransistor. Stray and ambient IR would make it difficult for the IR phototransistor to have a well-defined high or low output, wouldn't it? For a 5V system, if it isn't exactly 0V or 5V, it's floating?

Comment: Do you have a device in mind?

Comment: I'm currently using an LTR-301. You and @LeonHeller put me on a good track, though. ADC is definitely out since I don't need precise values. Following this RPi thread on phototransistor as a pull-down: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=5806&p=77270&hilit=GPIO+phototransistor